# Could not locate method: NeptuneGraphTraversal.values()

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, amazon-neptune, gremlinjs

I'm getting this error `Could not locate method: NeptuneGraphTraversal.values()` when running a query using gremlin for aws neptune. The specific query is this:

```js
import { process } from 'gremlin';

const { statics, t } = process;

    function getUsers() {
        return await this.query(g =>
            g
                .V()
                .match(
                    statics
                        .as('me')
                        .V(this.id)
                        // .has('user', t.id, this.id)
                        .fold()
                        .coalesce(
                            statics.unfold(),
                            statics.addV('user').property(t.id, this.id)
                        ),
                    statics.as('me').out('followed').out('followed').as('x'),
                    statics.as('x').not(statics.has(t.id, this.id)),
                    statics
                        .as('x')
                        .out('followed')
                        .has(t.id, this.id)
                        .count()
                        .is(0),
                    statics.as('x').in_('skip').has(t.id, this.id).count().is(0)
                )
                .select('x')
                .values(t.id)
                .dedup()
                .sample(3)
                .toList()
        );
    }
```

The error message suggests that neptune's `GraphTraversal` doesn't implement the [`values`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversal.html#values-java.lang.String...-) method, but I've reviewed the [implementation differences](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html) and there's no mention of that. What could be the problem? What alternatives can I consider?

Comment: This is likely due to the fact that you're using the `values()` step to extract the ID.  values() takes a string of a property key.  More likely what you need is the `id()` step.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it's the same error but with `id` instead of `values`. Any ideas why that's happening?

Comment: To be clear I did `.id()`, NOT `.id(t.id)`.

Comment: Never mind! I actually did do `.id(t.id)` by mistake. Using `.id()` made it work!! Thanks!! Please submit it as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to the fact that you're using the values() step to extract the ID. values() takes a string of a property key. More likely what you need is the id() step.